# Orfox (Android) not loads pages :( How to resolve?

Tags: orbot, network-configuration, android

I have downloaded yesterday on Andrid Orbot and Orfox. I turn Orbot on (I try with VPN, and Bridges too), but Orfox is not loads pages. The loading line is stopped on ca. 20%.

Orweb (the older tor browser) is works very fine, but orweb is not includes some things.

I have root permission, if this need.

Comment: Does Orbot connect to Tor (aka do you see the 100% number)? Can you connect to http://check.torproject.org/, if not, what happens?

Comment: I have a similar issue. The progressbar will load up to about 25% (or less) and will do nothing. I made sure orfox is sel3cted in orbot. Orfox will not load anything, with or without orbot.

Comment: I have the same, with my new phone it works, not with my (half year older) S5 phone.

Comment: Install on Orfox the add proxymob from http://tinyurl.com/getproxymob

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. However the OP doesn't give those information. So I will close this question.